# How to set "BitmapIcon" or "PathIcon" Content from "Canvas" Stored in resource dictionary?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to set "BitmapIcon" or "PathIcon" Content from "Canvas" Stored in resource dictionary?

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Canvas x:Key="appbaricon" Height=77 Width=77>
        <Path Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 25.3333,42.75C 26.5189, ..."/>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>

...

<BitmapIcon  ???Content???="{StaticResource appbaricon}">
```

Is there a way to set BitmapIcon's content using Canvas from Resource Dictionary? as in:

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon ???Content???="{StaticResource appbaricon}">
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resources can be any shareable object, such as styles, templates, brushes, and colors. However, controls, shapes, and other `FrameworkElements` are not shareable, so they can't be declared as reusable resources. For more info about sharing, see the [XAML resources must be shareable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#xaml-resources-must-be-shareable) section.

[`Canvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas) is a control which is not shareable that you cannot use is directly as one resource. As a workaround, I recommend you to create your own `AppBarButton` style as a resource and customize it . Inside the new `AppBarButton` style you could replace the default content of `Icon` to the `Canvas` you defined above, the `Icon` is defined by a `ViewBox` control in the style named `ContentViewbox` . For example:

```
<Page.Resources> 
    <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">    
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}">
                        ...

                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}"> 
                        ...
                            <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Margin="0,14,0,4">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="20">
                                    <Canvas Height="77" Width="77">
                                        <Path Data="F1 M 16,12 20,2L 20,16 1,16" Fill="#FF000000"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Viewbox>
                          ...
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">    
    <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" Label="PathIcon" />
</Grid>
```